# How to add all strings in a file to a set?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, set, init

Hello all (this is for python 2.7.12)

I'm trying to use a file that has 300,000 or so words in it, one per line, and add them all to a set inside my `__init__` method for my class. This is what I have so far.

I am not able to use the function it is returning errors for when I use anything but a string as a parameter. What am I doing wrong?

I want the set to have nothing but each word such as 'cat', 'car', 'dog', etc. inside of the set.

```
    def __init__(self,words):  # accepts a file of strings and puts them into a list
        self.language = set()
        for w in words:
            words.open()
            w.strip('\n')
            self.language.add(w)
        print self.language
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a file called *data.txt* you can read in the file into a list of words, strip out the new-line character and create a set from the list:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    raw = f.readlines()
words = [i.strip() for i in raw]
wordSet = set(words)
```

If you want to make a class you could define it as something like:

```
class listOfWords(object):
    """docstring for listOfWords."""
    def __init__(self, wordFile):
        self.wordFile = wordFile
        self.wordSet = self.readfile()

    def readfile(self):
        with open(self.wordFile) as f:
            wordSet = {line.rstrip() for line in f}
        return wordSet
```

Then create an object with:

```
wordObject = listOfWords('data.txt')
```

When you want to access the set of words you would call:

```
wordObject.wordSet
```

Comment: Thank you man! So I can use that method the same way in my class? I get confused sometimes because of all the 'self.' parameters you have to add to everything.

Comment: Also if I use just 'words' in place of data.txt will that mean I can use any file in my parameter?

Comment: Or replace every line after the `with` with just `wordSet = {line.rstrip() for line in f}` and avoid two completely unnecessary intermediate `list`s.

Comment: In terms of my code could you clarify what you mean @ShadowRanger? I am really confused by classes as this point even though they are just functions more or less...the syntax confuses me

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger that is a great short-cut!